# can't fetch json object with correct format

Tags: java, android, json

Suppose I am fetching from an api some `json` array as so

```
[{"id":1,"title":"title","description":"description","vote":null,"created_at":"2013-11-12T21:08:10.922Z","updated_at":"2013-11-12T21:08:10.922Z"}]
```

I want to retrieve this `json` as an `Some` object from `URL_Some` url

```
public class Some implements Serializable {

    private String id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String vote;
    private String created_at;
    private String updated_at;
    }//with all getters and setters
```

.

```
public List<Some> getSome() throws IOException {
        try {
            HttpRequest request = execute(HttpRequest.get(URL_Some));
            SomeWrapper response = fromJson(request, SomeWrapper.class);
            Field[] fields = response.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
            for (int i=0; i<fields.length; i++)
            {
                try {
                    Log.i("TAG", (String) fields[i].get(response));
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
                }
                Log.i("TAG", fields[i].getName());
            }
            if (response != null && response.results != null)
                return response.results;
            return Collections.emptyList();
        } catch (HttpRequestException e) {
            throw e.getCause();
        }
    }
```

and `SomeWrapper` is simply

```
private static class SomeWrapper {

        private List<Some> results;
    }
```

The problem is that I keep on getting this message

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY
```

**PS :** I use

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json should actually be like this:

`{"results": [{"id":1,"title":"title","description":"description","vote":null,"created_at":"2013-11-12T21:08:10.922Z","updated_at":"2013-11-12T21:08:10.922Z"}]}`

Gson will try to parse the json and create a SomeWrapper object. This alone tells Gson he will wait for a json with this format `{...}` since he's expecting an object. However you passed an array instead, that's why it complains about expecting BEGIN_OBJECT (`{`) but getting BEGIN_ARRAY instead (`[`). After that, it will expect this json object to have a `results` field, which will hold an array of objects.

You can create `List<Some>` directly without the need of a wrapper class however. To do so do this instead:

```
Type type= new TypeToken<List<Some>>() {}.getType();
List<Some> someList = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(jsonArray, type);
```

In this case, you can use the original json array you posted.

Comment: Thank you it worked, I just had to put in your `fromJson` method `Reader reader = request.bufferedReader();` because my `request` is just an interface

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you posted is a JSON array, which is indicated by the squared brackets around it: [ ].

You'd have to read the first object from the JSON array.

I personally use the [org.json](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) packages for Android JSON and parse my JSON in a manner like this:

```
private void parseJSON(String jsonString) {
JSONArray json;
    try {
        json = new JSONArray(jsonString);
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
        String id = jsonObject.getString("id");
    } catch (JSONException jsonex) {
        jsonex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If you've got multiple JSON objects in your array you can iterate over them by using a simple for loop (not for each!)

Comment: thank you but it si simpler to use `Gson` because it takes into account the class to wrap the `json`. Btw, I am very new to `android` : I tried to log the request variable as so : `Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(request))` but I have no input in my console. Could you explain it ?