# log outputs inconstantly - java

Tags: java, android, error-logging

In my android app, I call

```
        HttpRequest request = execute(HttpRequest.get(SOME_URL));//SOME_URL returns json
        Log.d("TAG", "hello");
        Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(request));
```

in my console `hello` outputs but not the second `log.d(...)`

Comment: @NathanWalters I put this `Boolean bool = (request != null);
            Log.d("TAG", "hello");
            Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(bool));` and it outputs true . So I don't understand why `Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(request));` doesn't output

Comment: According to the Android documentation, `HttpRequest` is an interface. I believe you can't get a `String` representing an interface. What exactly are you expecting to print? Are you getting any errors in LogCat?

Comment: @NathanWalters in fact I posted a question here `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19941755/cant-fetch-json-object-with-correct-format` and I didn't know how to solve it, so I wanted to debug...

Comment: That's your problem; I think `request` doesn't represent what you think it does. What does your `execute()` method do?

Comment: @NathanWalters, this project uses `com.github.kevinsawicki.http.HttpRequest;` (sorry I am a total newbie to `java`). I am trying this `File output = new File("src/request.out");
            HttpRequest.get(URL_LAWS).receive(output);` but I am told that the file (src/request.out) doesn't exist (I put this file in the `src` directory and set the right perms)...

Comment: @NathanWalters ok I found this method `public void execute() {
        execute(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace());
    }` in a class `SafeAsyncTask<ResultT>` implementing `Callable<ResultT>`

Comment: Do you have any idea what this does? What the output is? You should have a basic understanding of this stuff before you try to do anything.

Comment: @NathanWalters, yes that's the reason why I am trying to debug. How can I get the content of `request`. I tried with `File output` but I get an `no file found` error, even if I set the absolute path of `request.out`

Comment: That's what I'm trying to tell you; request is not, as far as I can tell, an Object. What is the return type of `execute()`?

Comment: @NathanWalters the method looks like `protected void execute( StackTraceElement[] launchLocation ) {
        this.launchLocation = launchLocation;
        executor.execute( future() );
    }` so it seems to be `void`, isn't it ?

Comment: So if it returns `void`, why do you expect it to have a value?

Comment: @NathanWalters sorry, I mislead, I found this method ` protected HttpRequest execute(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
        if (!configure(request).ok())
            throw new IOException("Unexpected response code: " + request.code());
        return request;
    }`

Comment: Where are you getting this method from?

Comment: from the same class the method `HttpRequest request = execute(HttpRequest.get(SOME_URL));` is called

Comment: I'm asking you where the implementation is. Is it a library? A method from another class? Can you provide the source for this method?

Comment: @NathanWalters I took it from here : `https://github.com/donnfelker/android-bootstrap/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/donnfelker/android/bootstrap/core/BootstrapService.java`

Comment: @NathanWalters finally the `SO` question was solved. But I am still interested in getting some file output but using `File output = new File("/Users/home/Downloads/android-bootstrap-master/app/src/request.out");
            HttpRequest.get(URL_LAWS).receive(output);` I get an `no file found error`, even if I set the absolute path of request.out `

Comment: Is that a valid file path in the Android file system? Do you have a LogCat stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

It wont log if the value of 'request' is null, check that it's actually returning something first.

edit:

Just thought, should you not be using:

```
Boolean.toString(bIn);
```

for outputting bools to strings?

Comment: Wouldnt `String.valueOf` return the `String` "null" in that case?

Comment: @Reimeus, I put this `Boolean bool = (request != null);
            Log.d("TAG", "hello");
            Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(bool));` and it outputs true . So I don't understand why `Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(request));` doesn't output